# C# Conversion failed when converting date/time

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get this exception when i run my ASP Web App

**Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.**
 When i debug i get error in the below piece of code
All variables with respect to date are in DATETIME format.

```
for (int j = 0; j < mapdate.Count; j++)
{
    string mapstartend = "Select Id,CDateTime from MAP1 where Product='" + pro[allpromap] + "' and ProgDate= '" + mapdate[j]+ "' and Channel='" + mapChannel[allmap] + "'";
    SqlCommand mapdat = new SqlCommand(mapstartend, conn);
    SqlDataReader mapdatrdr = mapdat.ExecuteReader();
    while (mapdatrdr.Read())
    {

        mapiddate.Add(mapdatrdr["Id"].ToString(), mapdatrdr.GetDateTime(1));
    }
    mapdatrdr.Close();
}
```

Comment: You are open for [**sql-injection**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx), use [`sql-parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx)! If `mapdate` is a `DateTime[]` it'll also solve this issue.

Comment: Is `CDateTime` ever NULL? It doesn't look like you are checking for that.

Comment: can you paste few sample values form mapdate list? also what is the type of mapdate? Also what is the execption?

Comment: inside that `for loop` I would wrap the `SqlCommand, SqlDataReader` around a `using(){}` you are going to run into some `GC` issue with that for loop let the `using()` handle the disposing of the objects since you are creating new instances that loop..

Answer (score 2):

If that's the problem then it's should work with

> DateTime.Parse()

But it'll be better if you use TryParse() for checking if the string were valid.

see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fw7727c.aspx) for more info how to use it

Answer (score 0):

What format is your date field in?

Trying using:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(mapdatrdr["CDateTime"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mapdatrdr.GetDateTime(columnIndex).ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
```

It should work